# How to search ocuurence of a string across all files in a directory using batch

Tags: string, batch-file

I need to search a string "style" across all html files present in a folder.
In the output I need file name and count of the occurrence of the string "style".
for eg output will be like

```
a.html  3
b.html   6
c.html  7
I have tried using
find /c "style" *.html
```

The problem is in one line it reads the string only once and moves to next 
i.e if a file has content:
 style style style style
style
It will read count as 2 only.
I need count as 5 and that too search should be across the folder.
Please help

Comment: Based on [Find occurrences of a string in files and display "filename - count" through batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31548600) - `for %%a in (*.html) do set /p ".=%%a: "<nul & call jrepl "style" "cnt+=1; false" /l /jmatch /jbeg "cnt=0" /jend "output.WriteLine(cnt)"`

Comment: i am not allowed to use anything except plain dos @wOxxOm

Comment: May the file names contain spaces?

Comment: we can assume files dont hae spaces

Comment: @AbhishekSenSharma, what is exactly `plain DOS`? It's not used anywhere today (well, there's FreeDOS project and similar, but that's different). Define your exact system characteristics in the question. Also `JREPL` runs on any modern Windows.

Comment: @Aacini you can be a bit polite. And its written inside folder.inside folder what is present is not mentioned it can be files or folder

Answer (score 1):

This should work, as long as the file names does not contain spaces, special Batch characters nor arithmetic operators (like `-`).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "word=style"

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "%word%" *.html') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   set "line=!line:"=!"
   for %%c in ("!line:%word%=" "!") do set /A "count[%%a]+=1"
   set /A "count[%%a]-=1"
)
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do echo %%a   %%b
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working fine @Aacini , but this is not working across the subfolder.Please provide a solution

Comment: The title clearly said: "all files in a directory" and the description adds: "all html files present in a folder". If you want to do an _additional request_ that modify the specifications of the original problem ("working across subfolders"), please clearly state this point and not present it as a missing feature in the solution!

Answer (score -1):

```
for /F "delims=" %G in ( 'findstr /S /M /I "style" "%CD%\*.html" ') do @find /c "style" "%~G" | findstr /V /R "^S"
```